# Suggestions for beginer in Robotics

Tags: reference-request

I am beginner in Robotics.I want to make serious start from scratch with interest but confused from where to start.So can anyone give some suggestions for 1.As a beginner in robotics ,**are there some simple and basic robots or circuit
designs which I can make by myself in the home**(so that I can gain practical knowledge of robots)? 2.or should I first read books (can anyone suggest some good reference  **book names,articles ,links,free on-line  video lecture series**)?

Answer (score 3):

Great to know that you are interested in Robotics. To start with robotics you should have a bit knowledge on how to do simple programs in C and if you have knowledge on Electronics and Mechanical then it will really help you out in designing robot parts understand the circuit and all.

For a beginner I would suggest you to check out [Arduino Tutorials](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage), since it is easy to learn and has a large user-base. You will need to buy many components for your robotic projects such as sensors, leds, wires, motors, camera, etc and it can sometimes be costly. Before buying any robotic parts from your nearby stores or other sites you should check the price of the same at these sites [Adafruit Shop](https://www.adafruit.com/category/), [Element14](http://element14.com), [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/), [Robot Marketplace](http://www.robotmarketplace.com/store.html) and [Hobbyking](http://hobbyking.com/) , maybe you will find a better option there.

Alternatively you can also check these sites to learn Arduino : [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-arduino), [Ladyada](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/), Sparkfun,[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials#arduino) and [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/howto/arduino/). Once you are done learning Arduino you can then learn PIC Microcontroller and following that embedded boards such as [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) and [Beaglebone Black](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK). By this time you will have good knowledge of how hardware and software works and you can then be able to dig into advances stuffs like Artificial intelligence and Autonomous bots.

Comment: sir , what
software tools are must
required on my laptop.?
Are they available on
internet for downloading
and free?Can u send me
link?

Comment: Which OS are you using??  Mac or windows or Ubuntu ??

Comment: sir,my laptop has OS of Windows

Comment: for Arduino there is an Arduino IDE for windows users -> http://arduino.cc/en/main/software

Comment: For raspberry pie and beaglebone black has its own Os in it. You can download different OS supporting that device like an image file or tar file and follow up tutorials on how to install it. But for arduino its pretty much simple , just need to plug in the device to ur laptop via usb and then open up arduino IDE and write a program and compile it and burn.

Comment: sure... Best wishes for your project...

Answer (score 1):

Great to see bright new minds interested in the field.

If you are a student you might want to look into [F.I.R.S.T. Robotics](http://usfirst.org), or **F**or **I**nspiration and **R**ecognition of **S**cience and **T**echnology.

This is not something you can do yourself at home, but it is a program that I would highly recommend, and you will be able to join any team, need not any prior experiences;the community is about sharing our knowledge with others.

This is a program based primarily in the US with teams across the world that is dedicated to inspiring young minds in the arts.

On the main page, you can go to the `Programs` section and select a program for more information.

I do not know your age, but this may help others as well:

- F.L.L. (Grades 4 to 8)
- F.T.C. (Grades 7 to 12)
- F.R.C. (Grades 9 to 12)

They also have available an event / team finder so you can check it out if you want!

[**Event & Team Finder**](http://www3.usfirst.org/whats-going-on)

Answer (score 0):

i wanna recommend to you 2 book :
[1]: Craig, John J. Introduction to robotics: mechanics and control. Addison-Wesley, 1989.

[2]: Spong, Mark W., Seth Hutchinson, and Mathukumalli Vidyasagar. Robot modeling and control. Wiley, 2006.
First book said simply lesson , you can esaily figure out 
i have studied both of them .